# In Oracle Apex Version 18.2, "text with autocomplete” displays all data but scroll bar causes window to close

Tags: oracle, autocomplete, oracle-apex

I am trying to use "text with autocomplete" option. It is working fine except when I try and use the scroll bar on the UI it closes the autocomplete. The arrows above and below the scroll wheel also causes problems. I can use the scroll wheel on my mouse and that works as expected.

I did find this post that talks about Version 18.1 not working but supposedly should work in 18.2. I am currently running V 18.2 and also tried it in 19.1 and it doesn't work either.

[Example of autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdl4a.png)

Comment: Example of autocomplete apex item                                                                                       
select  app_user_pkg.fullname(au.id) fullname --|| ' | ' || commissionId  fullname 
from app_user au 
join table l on au.id=l.app_user_id
order by 1

Comment: I found another website that had a similar problem from 2018 that isn't resolved. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4172088/apex-18-1-text-field-with-autocomplete-issue

Comment: I was able to recreate the problem in V 20.2 as well. Might just be a recurring bug. Any way to bypass this? 1

Comment: The scroll bar in the UI, or the mouse scroll wheel?  Do the cursor up/down keys scroll the list?

Comment: Scroll Bar in UI. Yes, the keyboards up/down keys scroll the list

Comment: I tried the solution in this post and turning 'On/Off' Lazy loading does not solve the problem either. https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4168805/18-1-text-field-with-autocomplete-issues